# Change accessibility label on state change after a button click

Tags: react-native, accessibility, touchableopacity

I have a set of touchable opacities used as selectable items. On clicking on one of these, that particular item is selected. I can see the change (visually) of the selection but on talkback it first reads the old accessibility label value and later on selecting it again reads out the correct value. From what I understand, talk back is reading the labels before the state change has taken place.

Is there a way that I can make talk back read the label after the state change has taken place?

Using accessibility states.

Comment: `accessibilityLabel` for the text and  `accessibilityStates` for the current state. `accessibilityStates` can have the following values: `selected`, `disabled`, `checked`, `unchecked`, `busy`, `expanded`, `collapsed`. I am checking accessibility state as `selected` to add text to the label